# Azure - BlobStore SAS uri command execution failed.

Tags: azure

When I try  to create a production deployment of a cloud service using the Azure portal and attempt to upload a package (a .cspkg file) I get the error message:

BlobStore SAS uri command execution failed. Details: Status Code =0, StatusText = none.

And I get the same message  when I attempt to upload a configuration (a .cscfg file).

The .cspkg and .cscfg files were both built by packaging a (tested) project in Visual Studio.

I only have one storage account and it's name  is correctly defaulting into the "Upload a Package" wizard in the Azure portal. So I don't think I can specify the storage resource it any other way.

Any idea what I can do or look at ?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I faced same issue in new azure portal. Switched back to old for uploading package and cloud config and it worked.

Comment: Hi @Hermant, Could you please explain how you "Switched back to old for uploading package and cloud config".

Comment: If I launch Manage.WindowsAzure.com, by default it loads old portal for me. Not sure how to go back from new portal to Old

Comment: I have the new portal. How do I get back to the old one?

Comment: @bitmanipulator, if you add this as answer, I'll mark it as such for you, thanks.

Comment: @Andrew, Hemant has already given the right solution and mentioned the link also in his comment. You should upvote his answer itself :)

Answer (score 1):

This same problem happens to me from time to time on a project that otherwise has no problem being deployed to azure. Restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding the azure project usually removes the problem during upload.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I got contributor rights to one of our company Azure accounts for cloud services. I got also all connection strings for storage and service bus etc. But i did not get any other rights in the portal. So the storage accounts did not show up when i selected this directory in the portal.

When i uploaded the packages then azure requires a storage account from the current subscription and it must be visible there - it is not possible to just enter a connection string.

After i got the rights to one storage account (and selected it), i was finally able to upload packages just fine.

It still does not work from withing visual studio - as i understood co-admin rights for the subscription would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue and I've just spent some time trying to at least make it work.

It turned out that when I was creating a storage account (used for my deployment) in the new portal, I kept the default "Resource manager" for the "Deployment model" parameter.

I created another storage account selecting "Classic" for the parameter this time. And pointed my deployment upload to this "classic" storage. It helped! :)

I am still figuring out what's just happened, but it looks like you should use a "classic" storage account because you are using a "classic" cloud service.

In "All resources", the storage accounts with different deployment models will look differently: the classic one will look blue, the "resource manager" one will look greenish. We need the blue one :)