# BizSpark Azure CloudService Staging update fail

Tags: azure, cloud

I have a simple cloudservice on azure under a bizspark account.  It is running fine.

I wish to update it and have done so many times in the past.

Currently I cannot as it fails to upload both the package and configuration files with the following error: "Blobstore SAS uri command execution failed. Details: StatusCode = 0, StatusText = ."

Google has been no help to date.

Comment: Looking at the response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345539/azure-blobstore-sas-uri-command-execution-failed, it seems to be an issue with new portal. Can you try doing the same in old portal? Also see if this thread helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b2df44be-2d00-4f18-800c-9ac5d214cbc6/bizspark-problem-with-azure-access?forum=windowsazuremanagement.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri. I've had a look at those two links.  It is still really unclear to me looking at my Azure management console, what I am supposed to do.

Do I create a new (different kind of) Cloud Service from scratch or do I do something to the one I already have - of type "Cloud service (classic)" running in the Staging environment.