# Error During Upload azure worker role package

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-cloud-services

I am facing the problem during upload the package on azure cloud service web role. It is showing error **"blobstore sas uri command execution failed "**.

I have already go through with some link we did not get any working solution [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345539/azure-blobstore-sas-uri-command-execution-failed)

How could we resolve this problem?[image: This is snapshot for reference]

Comment: Reaaally tough to help you with nothing included other than a brief error message. Please edit with more details. Maybe it's related to the `cspkg` size being too big? Are there more details to the error message?

Comment: this is the exact error "BlobStore SAS uri command execution failed. Details: StatusCode = 0 , StatusText = none."  that i am getting when I am going to update new worker role package.

Comment: .cspkg size is less than 5MB and I am uploading package through portal

Comment: *Please* edit your question. Details shouldn't go in comments - much harder to read (especially when unformatted errors like what you posted).

Comment: If you have tried to use different types storage account, ("Resource Managerment", "Classical") and another way that re-deployment with Visual Studio,and  it still not work. Please have a try to delete the 'azureportaldeploy' container that will automatical created in your storage account after choose the uploaded storage on the azure portal. After that refresh the azure portal and try it again.